# how to add your dcom project to component services

Tags: vb6, dcom, component-services

So, I am trying to add in a new dll to an old project (that I didn't start). It all goes well, in that I am able to add a dll and use its functions - no problem. However, when it came time to test the project, after building it and packaging the installer, i ran into i bit of a pinch.

Now I'm totally new to this, so I had to undergo a lot of googling the interwebs to learn how to package projects and dcom objects. Additional info: With regards to how this project is coded/packaged prior to my modifications, there was none. But! it did come with neat instructions regarding how to set the access permissions in the dcomcnfg (Component Services). The DCOM object was "ProjectCom.ProjectInfo".

I tried real hard to package and repackage the new project (even including a dll that the old project used but isn't used by the new one) but I could never seem to get the installation to add the ProjectCom.ProjectInfo entry in dcomcnfg >.< (I only knew of this ProjectCom.ProjectInfo because I kept a copy of the old installation package and run-tested the installations for comparison.)

In a nutshell, the question is: How do i get my own ProjectCom.ProjectInfo to show up in dcomcnfg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I haven't been searching long enough on google when i wrote the above question.　DCOM objects are apparently automatically added to dcomcnfg.exe upon installation. However, mine just didn't show up until after the ProgramInfo.exe is run the first time.

No prob here. Move along. Move along.

Comment: Afterwards, i discovered that installers can actually include script for ActiveX exe to self register themselves.